# Python Selenium Error: PlacementList must be sorted by first 8 bits of display_id

Tags: python, selenium

I try to use Python and Selenium, but I get this error: PlacementList must be sorted by first 8 bits of display_id

How can I solve this?

This is the code:

```
from selenium import webdriver

e = "C:/Downloads/edgedriver_win64/msedgedriver.exe"

driver = webdriver.Edge(e)
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps

```
from selenium import webdriver

from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())

driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried this, but still I get the same error:
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:59040/devtools/browser/48455ba6-dddf-4337-beb3-0e4d1e8910bf
[19136:13012:0921/125049.856:ERROR:display_layout.cc(559)] PlacementList must be sorted by first 8 bits of display_id

Comment: Tried different browsers. I have been working on the script, and everything works finedespite the error messages.

Comment: try this options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='<path-to-chrome>', options=options

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `chrome` as a browser try the following code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromiumService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.core.utils import ChromeType

browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromiumService(ChromeDriverManager(chrome_type=ChromeType.CHROMIUM).install()))
browser.get('www.your-website.com')
```

However, I advise using `Firefox` which is the more stable one as follow.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()))

# Open the Website
driver.get('https://www.your-website.com')
print(driver.title)
driver.quit()
```